# Flutter insert list from mySQL to options in FormBuilderCheckboxList

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

i am getting data from mySQL as list of users.

in formbuilder there is a list as an example:

```
['English', 'German', 'French']
```

I have change it to options: item and it worked once but now I am getting an error

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StepperBody(dirty, state: _StepperBodyState#98968):
> The method 'map' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => FormBuilderFieldOption)

It has worked a few times, after app restart it stopped to work so I have change it back to current list.

how can i asign async list to formbuilder?

the code:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//import 'package:validate/validate.dart';  //for validation
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'main_.dart';

class MyData {
  String title;
  String days;
  String words;
  String rep;
  String gender;
  var username;

  MyData({this.gender, this.title, this.days, this.words, this.rep, this.username,
  });

}

class StepperBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StepperBodyState createState() => _StepperBodyState();
}

class _StepperBodyState extends State<StepperBody> {
  int currStep = 0;
  static var _focusNode = FocusNode();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  static MyData data = MyData();


  List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKeys = [
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>()
  ];

  String _key = "786465659081B207EB5BF1EF9AF7552A6";
  String _api = "https://10.0.2.2/api/";

  Future<List> senddata() async {
    final response = await http.post(
        _api + "insert_data.php?key=" + _key, body: {
      "username": data.username,
    });
    var resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(resp.toString());
  }

  Future<List> getData() async{
    var url = _api + "get_data.php?key=" + _key;
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(resp.toString());
    data.username = resp.map<String>((m) => m['username'] as String).toList();
    print(data.username);
  }
  List item = data.username as List;


  List<Step> steps = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print('Has focus: $_focusNode.hasFocus');
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    steps = [
      Step(
          title: const Text('Users'),
          //subtitle: const Text('Subtitle'),
          isActive: true,
          //state: StepState.editing,
          state: StepState.indexed,
          content: Form(
            key: formKeys[0],
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
              FormBuilder(
              key: _fbKey,
              autovalidate: true,
               child: FormBuilderCheckboxList(
                  decoration:
                  InputDecoration(labelText: "Languages you know"),
                  attribute: "languages",
                  initialValue: ["English"],
                  options: ['English', 'German', 'French']
                  .map((gender) => FormBuilderFieldOption(
                   value: gender, child: Text("$gender")))
                  .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ),
    ];

    void showSnackBarMessage(String message,
        [MaterialColor color = Colors.red]) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
    }

    void _submitDetails() {
      final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;
      final FormBuilderState fbKeyState = _fbKey.currentState;
/*
      _fbKey.currentState.save();
      if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
        print(_fbKey.currentState.value);
      }

 */
      if (!fbKeyState.validate()) {
        showSnackBarMessage('Please enter correct data');
        senddata();

      } else {
        showSnackBarMessage('Saved');
        formState.save();
        senddata();
          print("Name: ${data.username}");



        _fbKey.currentState.save();
        if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
          print(_fbKey.currentState.value);
        }
      }
    }

    return Container(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
            Stepper(
              steps: steps,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              type: StepperType.vertical,
              currentStep: this.currStep,
              onStepContinue: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (formKeys[currStep].currentState.validate()) {
                    if (currStep < steps.length - 1) {
                      currStep = currStep + 1;
                    } else {
                      currStep = 0;
                    }
                  }
                  // else {
                  // Scaffold
                  //     .of(context)
                  //     .showSnackBar( SnackBar(content:  Text('$currStep')));

                  // if (currStep == 1) {
                  //   print('First Step');
                  //   print('object' + FocusScope.of(context).toStringDeep());
                  // }

                  // }
                });
              },
              controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                  {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                return Row(
                  //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //
                    RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text("Forward", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: onStepContinue,
                    ),

                    SizedBox(width: 15,),
                    RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text("Back", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: onStepCancel,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              onStepCancel: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (currStep > 0) {
                    currStep = currStep - 1;
                  } else {
                    currStep = 0;
                  }
                });
              },
              onStepTapped: (step) {
                setState(() {
                  currStep = step;
                });
              },
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                'Save',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                var submitDetails = _submitDetails;
                submitDetails();
              },
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
            ),
          ]),
        ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: "test",),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  MyAppScreenMode createState() => MyAppScreenMode();
}

class MyAppScreenMode extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        ),
        home: new Scaffold(

          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Test stepper'),
          ),
          body: new StepperBody(),

        ));
  }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting this error is due to the fact that at the time the `build` method is executed the value of `data.username` is null. This is because the value of the `username` property is only set after it has been fetched asynchronously from the database, by which time the `build` method may or may not have already executed. I have updated your code sample to show how you could use the `FutureBuilder` widget to wait for the data to be fetched from the database asynchronously before displaying it in the `FormBuilderCheckboxList` widget. I would recommend taking a look at the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for more information about the `FutureBuilder` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';

class MyData {
  String title;
  String days;
  String words;
  String rep;
  String gender;
  var username;

  MyData({this.gender, this.title, this.days, this.words, this.rep, this.username,
  });

}

class StepperBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StepperBodyState createState() => _StepperBodyState();
}

class _StepperBodyState extends State<StepperBody> {
  int currStep = 0;
  static var _focusNode = FocusNode();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  Future<List<String>> _future;

  List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKeys = [
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>()
  ];

  String _key = "786465659081B207EB5BF1EF9AF7552A6";
  String _api = "https://10.0.2.2/api/";

  Future<void> senddata(List<String> username) async {
    final response = await http.post(
        _api + "insert_data.php?key=" + _key, body: {
      "username": username,
    });
    var resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(resp.toString());
  }

  Future<List<String>> getData() async {
    var url = _api + "get_data.php?key=" + _key;
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(resp.toString());
    return resp.map<String>((m) => m['username'] as String).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _future = getData();

    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print('Has focus: $_focusNode.hasFocus');
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void showSnackBarMessage(String message,
        [MaterialColor color = Colors.red]) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
    }

    void _submitDetails(List<String> username) {
      final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;
      final FormBuilderState fbKeyState = _fbKey.currentState;
/*
      _fbKey.currentState.save();
      if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
        print(_fbKey.currentState.value);
      }

 */
      if (!fbKeyState.validate()) {
        showSnackBarMessage('Please enter correct data');
        senddata(username);

      } else {
        showSnackBarMessage('Saved');
        formState.save();
        senddata(username);
        print("Name: $username");



        _fbKey.currentState.save();
        if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
          print(_fbKey.currentState.value);
        }
      }
    }

    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: _future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final steps = [
            Step(
              title: const Text('Users'),
              //subtitle: const Text('Subtitle'),
              isActive: true,
              //state: StepState.editing,
              state: StepState.indexed,
              content: Form(
                key: formKeys[0],
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FormBuilder(
                      key: _fbKey,
                      autovalidate: true,
                      child: FormBuilderCheckboxList(
                        decoration:
                        InputDecoration(labelText: "Languages you know"),
                        attribute: "languages",
                        initialValue: ["English"],
                        options: snapshot.data
                            .map((gender) => FormBuilderFieldOption(
                            value: gender, child: Text("$gender")))
                            .toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];

          return Container(
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                  Stepper(
                    steps: steps,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    type: StepperType.vertical,
                    currentStep: this.currStep,
                    onStepContinue: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (formKeys[currStep].currentState.validate()) {
                          if (currStep < steps.length - 1) {
                            currStep = currStep + 1;
                          } else {
                            currStep = 0;
                          }
                        }
                        // else {
                        // Scaffold
                        //     .of(context)
                        //     .showSnackBar( SnackBar(content:  Text('$currStep')));

                        // if (currStep == 1) {
                        //   print('First Step');
                        //   print('object' + FocusScope.of(context).toStringDeep());
                        // }

                        // }
                      });
                    },
                    controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                        {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                      return Row(
                        //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          //
                          RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: Text("Forward",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                            onPressed: onStepContinue,
                          ),

                          SizedBox(width: 15,),
                          RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: Text(
                                "Back", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                            onPressed: onStepCancel,
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                    onStepCancel: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (currStep > 0) {
                          currStep = currStep - 1;
                        } else {
                          currStep = 0;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    onStepTapped: (step) {
                      setState(() {
                        currStep = step;
                      });
                    },
                  ),

                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Save',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      var submitDetails = _submitDetails;
                      submitDetails(snapshot.data);
                    },
                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  ),
                ]),
              ));
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: "test",),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  MyAppScreenMode createState() => MyAppScreenMode();
}

class MyAppScreenMode extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        ),
        home: new Scaffold(

          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Test stepper'),
          ),
          body: new StepperBody(),

        ));
  }
}
```